# Variable says it is False when run in the function, but then it reverts back to True

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am currently creating a tic-tac-toe game for a course. It has been going great, however, I have hit a roadblock. I am having trouble with the part when I want to check if a player has won or not, it is a function (called "game_over"). When I run the game, and if the "if" statement is met, it says "game_on = False". However, once the player while loop begins, it reverts back to True. Thus the game never stops.

```
game_on = True
player_ready = False
game_finish = False
turn = "Player1"


# THE BOARD
line1 = ["|", "___" , "|", "___", "|","___","|"]
line2 = ["|", "___" , "|", "___", "|","___","|"]
line3 = ["|", "___" , "|", "___", "|","___","|"]

list1 = ''.join(line1)
list2 = ''.join(line2)
list3 = ''.join(line3)
print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)

# FUNCTIONS AND THE GAME
Player1_character = "x"

def game_over(player,character):

  if line1[1] == (f"_{character}_") and line1[3] == (f"_{character}_") and line1[5] == (f"_{character}_"):
    game_on = False
    print(f"Game Over, {player} won!game_on = {game_on}")
    return





def print_character(numbers,char):
    if numbers == 1:
        line1[1] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 2:
        line1[3] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 3:
        line1[5] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 4:
        line2[1] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 5:
        line2[3] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 6:
        line2[5] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 7:
        line3[1] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 8:
        line3[3] = (f"_{char}_")

    if numbers == 9:
        line3[5] = (f"_{char}_")

    list1 = ''.join(line1)
    list2 = ''.join(line2)
    list3 = ''.join(line3)
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    print(list3)




section = 0
# Tutorial Goes Here
while game_on == True:
    # Selecting Players
    while player_ready == False:
        Player1_character = ""
        Player1_character = input("Player1 choose your character 'x' or 'o': ")
        Player2_character = "|"

        if Player1_character == "x":
            Player2_character = "o"
        elif Player1_character == "o":
            Player2_character = "x"

        print(f"Player1 = {Player1_character} ||| Player2 = {Player2_character}")
        print("LETS BEGIN!!!\n")
        player_ready = True

    #Starting game:
    while turn == "Player1":
        section = int(input(f"Player1's Turn: \nSelect where you want to put your '{Player1_character}'(1-9){game_on}: "))
        print_character(section, Player1_character)

        if game_on == False:
          break

        turn = "Player2"



    while turn == "Player2":
        section = int(input(f"Player2's Turn: \nSelect where you want to put your '{Player2_character}'(1-9){game_on}: "))
        print_character(section, Player2_character)
        game_over("Player2",Player2_character)
        if game_on == False:
          break
        turn = "Player1"
```

Comment: `game_on = False` inside `game_over` is a separate local variable, *not* the global the loop uses.

Comment: I think it would be a better approach to avoid globals and instead make your `game_over` function return (lets say `False`) and then in the main loop change to `if game_over("Player2",Player2_character) == False: break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Python Programming FAQ on [the rules for using global variables in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python).

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.